# prevent touchpad click while typing in a VM

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtual-machine, vmware, touchpad

I use a Fedora 19 VM (VMware Workstation 9) on top of a Windows 7 laptop (Dell Latitude E6530) on a regular basis.  In Windows and native Linux, I can configure the touchpad to not accept clicks while I'm typing on the keyboard.  With the VM, however, it appears Windows passes the touchpad events through directly, and since the device is exposed to the VM as a normal mouse, I can't use the touchpad-specific tools to prevent clicks while typing (normally I'd use syndaemon).  Is there any way I can prevent these clicks, or get the VM to see the touchpad as an actual touchpad?

Answer (score 1):

Use `touchfreeze` from here: https://code.google.com/p/touchfreeze/

This should work and hope this helps